# How can I insert address blocks on the left and right side of the page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, boxes

I want to insert my local address on the left side of the page and my permanent address on the right side of the page. However, I want both address blocks to be left-aligned. Basically, I want something that looks like this:

[image]

I originally rendered this with the `res` package, which simply asks you to input the address with the `\address` command and renders it when you use `\begin{resume}...\end{resume}`. The package is not very flexible with how I can render the rest of the page, which is why I want to manually render this.

How do I emulate this behavior? I've tried fiddling around with boxes (particularly the `\makebox` and `\mbox` commands, which apparently don't support newlines) but I haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: Related question if using `letter` class: [easily aligning from and to address fields in latex letters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33268/easily-aligning-from-and-to-address-fields-in-latex-letters)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  The way I would choose to do it is to use a `\minipage` and specify the width of the two minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.60\linewidth}
\textbf{Local Address}\par
123 Main Street\par
Anytown, XXX\par
Email: foo@bar.com
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
\textbf{Permanent Address}\par
656 Somewhere\par
Some Other Town, YYY\par
Phone: 555-555-1212
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use a `tabular` environment such and use `p{3.5in}` to fix the width of the first column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.5in}l}
\textbf{Local Address} & \textbf{Permanent Address}\\
123 Main Street        & 656 Somewhere\\
Anytown, XXX           & Some Other Town, YYY\\
Email: foo@bar.com     & Phone: 555-555-1212
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

If you really want to use the `\makebox` command, you need to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makebox[3.5in][l]{\textbf{Local Address}} \textbf{Permanent Address}\\
\makebox[3.5in][l]{123 Main Street}        656 Somewhere\\
\makebox[3.5in][l]{Anytown, XXX}           Some Other Town, YYY\\
\makebox[3.5in][l]{Email: foo@bar.com}     Phone: 555-555-1212
\end{document}
```

The first paramter to `\makebox` specifies the width to be 3.5in, and the `[l]` specifies that the text to be placed in that box is to be left aligned.  The `\noindent` was needed so that TeX does not add the usual indentation of the first paragraph.  Instead of `\\` at the end you could also have used `\par\noindent`.

---

Similarily, there is also the `\parbox` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\parbox{3.5in}{\textbf{Local Address}} \textbf{Permanent Address}\\
\parbox{3.5in}{123 Main Street}        656 Somewhere\\
\parbox{3.5in}{Anytown, XXX}           Some Other Town, YYY\\
\parbox{3.5in}{Email: foo@bar.com}     Phone: 555-555-1212
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dang, you beat me by 20 seconds. I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it using the [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth). It provides the `varwidth` environment that is similar to `minipage`, but allows for a "natural width" rather than the "fixed width" box of `minipage`.

Two examples below show how you can (i) align your addresses flush left and right with the page margin, or (ii) right-align (`\raggedleft`) the second address at 50% of the text block width. Other options, of course, are also available. Although possible, neither of these options are that easy to do in a general way using `minipage` due to it's fixed width nature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
\begin{document}
% ========= local address left | permanent address right
\noindent\begin{varwidth}{0.5\linewidth} % local address
  Local Address\par
  123 Main Street\par
  Anytown, XXX\par
  Email: foo@bar.com
\end{varwidth} \hfill
\begin{varwidth}{0.5\linewidth}% permanent address
  Permanent Address\par
  656 Somewhere\par
  Some Other Town, YYY\par
  Phone 555-555-1212
\end{varwidth}

\bigskip

% ========= local left | permanent middle
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth} % local address
  Local Address\par
  123 Main Street\par
  Anytown, XXX\par
  Email: foo@bar.com
\end{minipage}%
\begin{varwidth}{0.5\linewidth}% permanent address
  \raggedleft
  Permanent Address\par
  656 Somewhere\par
  Some Other Town, YYY\par
  Phone 555-555-1212
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) with the `showframe` option was merely used to showcase the page layout boundaries.